# Adding an excel database to an existing shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-database, attribute-joins, excel

I have a spreadsheet with various feature data; I would like to add this data to an existing shapefile.  I have a common column in both the shapefile and the excel data.  I would like to be able to add symbols of the new data to the drawing.  I am working with ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include details of what you have tried so far and exactly where you are stuck, please?  You seem to already realise that you need to use a Join.

Comment: I have formatted my excel file to ESRI standards no spaces, headers are the feature titles, no dashes etc.  I then inserted this table and joined it with the existing shapefile.  The features appear to become joined within the attribute table of the shapefile but the data shows up as "null'.

Comment: Check whether the data type is the same for both columns (e.g. both `text`, or both `int`, etc.). This is frequently the problem with "failed" joins.

Comment: They are both "double"

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with any clarifications that we request via comments, please?  That way the question is standalone rather than requiring potential answerers to read a trail of comments.

Comment: Is your destination layer point, line, or polygon?

Comment: My destination is a Point.

Comment: Disagree, the user wants to append features from excel to a layer, not append just attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

1. Use [Make XY Event Laye](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006z000000)r to create temp points from excel (based on x/y columns)
2. [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) or [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) (database schema has to be the same for append option) event layer to destination shapefile

OR

1. Use [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000027000000) to convert excel to .dbf or feature class table
2. Use [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to get x/y coordinates and attributes from table, and then use [insert cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) to create new features in destination layer

Comment: +1 because although the Q is a dupe, this answer is not. A join only works when you already have geometry to link a table to, whereas these methods can be used to create new features.

Answer (score -1):

I know that you're looking for an answer that uses ArcGIS but if you're willing to use QGIS instead, then here is a pluggin called mmqgis. This plugin simply join a shapefile with an excel database.

Comment: Where should I download QGIS from and will i then be able to bring the results back into ArcGIS as a shapefile?

Comment: The fastest way will be to do the same with Arcgis, but of course if you do this with QGIS you can then export the join shapefile and open it in Arcgis :)

Comment: Thanks but where should i download it?

Comment: Install QGIS (http://www.qgis.org/fr/site/) then launch it. Find "extension tool" and select mmqgis. The install will be very simple.

Comment: Ive installed QGIS and the pluggin, could you step me through the process to join the csv table with the shapefile